# SVN: Create patch from specific revision to head

Tags: windows, svn

I have a computer that is offline from the network, but shares some svn directories with computers that are on the network.

About once a month I need to update the directories on the offline computer with the changes that have happened in the repos. The current way I do this is to zip the directories, burn on cd and unzip on the offline computer.

I thought there must be an easier way to do this, so I thought of getting all the files that were changed from the last time and only zip those. But then I would miss out on changing deleted files.

So I there a way to create a patch from a revision to head? I've searched but haven't found anything useful.

Both computers run win7.

Comment: Eventually this was 'solved' by migrating the version control from svn to git...

Answer (score 0):

If you know the revision of the last change, you could run a
`svn diff -r revision:HEAD`

to get the list of changes on all files.

You could add --summarize to get a list of files alone (without the actual diffs)

```
svn diff --summarize -r revision:HEAD
```

which could then be piped into a zip command to just get the files that were changed.

Refer [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.c.diff)

Comment: He would still have to make all the delete operations by hand.

Comment: yes I've looked into diff with summarize, and the deletions would be a problem. could perhaps do a script that deleted files marked 'D' in the diff file

Comment: Could you do a patch with just the changes and when applying the patch, add the "-E" (--remove-empty-files option) so that it gets deleted ?

Answer (score 0):

If the repository isn't too large and can fit entirely on an USB stick / CD, you can do this:

1. Create a copy of the repo on the USB stick / CD.
2. Plug the USB stick in the offline computer, and svn checkout the files straight out of the repo on the USB stick, using the `file:///` schema ([documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.basic.in-action.wc.tbl-1)).
3. Monthly, do the same process again, only instead of checking out from the USB repo, simply plug the USB stick and run `svn update`. If you've copied the latest version of the repo in the same directory on the USB stick, the update should run just fine.

Comment: that would have been nice, but the repo is too big for a usb. :/